# Hide faces of a box geometry that won't be seen by the camera in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm making a project that includes many squares and if too many are rendered than it makes it really laggy. Is there a way to check if there is a block right next to it and not render a face of it in order to make it run faster?

Currently I am making boxes using 6 different planes and moving them around to make a box. I am aware this is not the most efficient way to do it and I have fixed that as of right now and that was the best way for my little brain to visualize it. Here is the code that checks if there is another box next to it:

```
let blRight = false
let blLeft = false
let blBack = false
let blFront = false
let blTop = false
let blBottom = false

for(let i = 0; i < blocks.coord.x.length; i++) {
    if(blocks.coord.x[i] == x + 10) {
        if(!blocks.coord.y[i] == y) {
            blRight = true
        }
    }
}
for(let i = 0; i < blocks.coord.x.length; i++) { 
    if(blocks.coord.x[i] == x - 10) {
        if(!blocks.coord.y[i] == y) {
            blLeft = true
        }
    }
}
for(let i = 0; i < blocks.coord.y.length; i++) {
    if(blocks.coord.y[i] == y + 10) {
        blTop = false
    }
}
for(let i = 0; i < blocks.coord.y.length; i++) {
    if(blocks.coord.y[i] == y - 10) {
        blBottom = true
    }
}
for(let i = 0; i < blocks.coord.z.length; i++) {
    if(blocks.coord.z[i] == z + 10) {
        if(!blocks.coord.y[i] == y) {
            blFront = true
        }
    }
}
for(let i = 0; i < blocks.coord.z.length; i++) {
    if(blocks.coord.z[i] == x - 10) {
        if(!blocks.coord.y[i] == y) {
            blBack = true
        }
    }
}

if(blRight == false) {
    scene.add(right)
}
if(blLeft == false) {
    scene.add(left)
}
if(blTop == false) {
    scene.add(blockTop)
}
if(blBottom == false) {
    scene.add(bottom)
}
if(blFront == false) {
    scene.add(front)
}
if(blBack == false) {
    scene.add(back)
}

blocks.coord.x.push(x)
blocks.coord.y.push(y)
blocks.coord.z.push(z)
blocks.coord.id.push(3)
```

This is in a function that is called to make a new block. blTop meaning top face and so on. This is actually how Minecraft makes its game faster. Any suggestions to make it more effecient?

Comment: Honestly, recomputing the faces to draw for every mesh for every frame, and sending that data to the GPU, is most likely _less efficient_ than any lag you're experiencing. Even Occlusion Culling (which can hide things that covered by other parts) has overhead, and would not work well for the very basic scenario you're describing. IF there's more to it, please add more details, and code that replicates the problem and shows your attempts at resolving it.

Comment: Ok, i do have some attempts at doing this, although it didnt work very well and I will update my question with it

Comment: @OwenOdroski If your blocks are in a perfect grid, and your scene is static, or blocks are added/removed only infrequently, like in Minecraft, consider splitting your geometry into batches and calculating only the visible part of each batch and rendering that. When a block is updated, you rebuild the batch it belongs to.

Comment: In the Minecraft scenario, I would build checks into the Render List creation to help discard certain blocks/faces. 1. (Boolean) Track whether any faces of a block are uncovered--for covered blocks you can skip checking its faces. 2. (Boolean) Track whether a face is uncovered or not--covered faces can be skipped entirely. 3. (Vector math) Don't add faces whose normal points "away" from the camera.

Comment: Regarding the code you posted, you're looping though each axis twice. Consolidate the loops.

Comment: Thank you to all who put suggestions. I will answer my own question when I figure it out!